# Rss20FeedFormatter and pre-RSS2 formats

Tags: c#, rss, syndication

I have some C# code which uses the Rss20FeedFormatter class to produce RSS output on a web page. Our client wants the feed I am writing to be compatible to an existing feed they use. This uses an old version of RSS:

```
<rss version="0.91fn">
```

However the Rss20FeedFormatter seems to be limited to

```
<rss version="2.0">
```

I don't want any RSS2 features, but there doesn't seem to be a SyndicationFeed which allows me to produce earlier versions of RSS.

Is there another class or method I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out myself. You have to write your own class which inherits from SyndicationFeedFormatter and implements all the methods. I didn't bother with the read methods just the write methods, as that's all I was doing.